# Can we use android studio while downloading updates or components

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio regularly gets updates.but while downloading updates or any other component we can not use the development environment. because it takes about 15 minutes on an average to download updates so that time gets wasted. is there a way to use it while components are being downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I setup the android sdk in my classpath so that I can run the android on the command line and then run the updates from there.

```
# Android SDK development
if [ -d "/usr/local/opt/android-sdk" ]; then
  export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/opt/android-sdk"
  launchctl setenv ANDROID_HOME $ANDROID_HOME
  export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/22.0.1"
fi
```

I never do the updates from Android Studio. I run the android application and do the updates from there so I can still work in Android Studio. Once the updates are completed, I restart Android Studio.

**This is annoying behave for sure!**

If you are on mac or linux; update your classpath to include android from the sdk.If you are on windows, you should be able to run the executable.